# Insert Chapter 1 without naming the chapter

Tags: lyx

Document Class: Book (Standard Class)

I want to create chapter 1, then my info below.

But every time I type Chapter 1 - Its prompting to be named, how do I get around this? I have checked google but don't see anything.

Also I need to remove the date at the top of the document.
I will have the Title, Author, Table of Contents, then Chapter 1...

But its popping in date between author and Table of contents.

The last section would be the Paragraph, I want to have the first line on each line to be indented.

```
\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
Space
\end_layout

\begin_layout Author
John Williams
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset toc
LatexCommand tableofcontents

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Paragraph
\begin_inset Quotes eld
\end_inset

Mom could you tell me what father does in space?
\begin_inset Quotes erd
\end_inset
```

This is what part of the file looks like in notepad++.

**EDIT:**

Here is all the code from my document and all the settings and few lines in the document.

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass book
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family sfdefault
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize 10
\spacing onehalf
\use_hyperref true
\pdf_bookmarks true
\pdf_bookmarksnumbered false
\pdf_bookmarksopen false
\pdf_bookmarksopenlevel 1
\pdf_breaklinks false
\pdf_pdfborder false
\pdf_colorlinks false
\pdf_backref false
\pdf_pdfusetitle true
\papersize letterpaper
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 1in
\topmargin 1.25in
\rightmargin 1in
\bottommargin 1.25in
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 0
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 2
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
Space
\end_layout

\begin_layout Author
John Williams
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset toc
LatexCommand tableofcontents

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Paragraph
\begin_inset Quotes eld
\end_inset

Mom could you tell me what father does in space?
\begin_inset Quotes erd
\end_inset


\end_layout
\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable (yet minimal) code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Can you please edit this question to be one question? To get Chapter 1 with no name, you can press ctrl+space in LyX, then do return. Does that work?

Comment: To remove the date, add `\date{}` in Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble.

Answer (score 1):

Summary of comments:

- To remove the date from the titlepage, go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble, and add

  ```
  \date{}
  ```
- A workaround for the requirement of having text in the chapter title is to add some text that isn't visible. I'd suggest an empty ERT-box, i.e. hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, right arrow key, and then enter. A non-breaking space, added with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> will also work.